# SQL - Email query range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql job which queries the database. The job is scheduled to run every 24 hours and it sends out an email with required data which has a query range from 07:30 today to 07:30 the previous day. Here is the code for the heading of my email :

```
INSERT INTO @ReportContentBuilder VALUES('<h4>Query Range :  ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@StartTimestamp)
            + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar, @StartTimestamp, 106) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, @StartTimestamp, 108)
            + ' (UTC) to ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@EndTimestamp) + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar, @EndTimestamp, 106)
            + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, @EndTimestamp, 108) + ' (UTC)</h4>')
```

Here is the value I have for @StartTimestamp:

```
SET @StartTimestamp = CAST((CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndTimestamp), 106) + ' 07:30') as datetime)
```

Here is the expected output for my email heading :

**Query Range : Wednesday, 19 Nov 2014 07:30:00 (UTC) to Thursday, 20 Nov 2014 07:30:00 (UTC)**

My question is what value do I use for @EndTimestamp??

If I use GETUTCDATE() and the job runs 2 mins late then the range is incorrect. I also don't want to hardcode it because of the changes needed for daylight savings each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that the "dynamic" part is the difference between current time (GETUTCDATE()) and 7:30 . So with @timeDiff you can handle this dynamic part of the ecuation. Try this (replace last select with your needed insert; I only tested the output):

```
DECLARE @StartTimestamp datetime
DECLARE @EndTimestamp datetime = GETUTCDATE()

DECLARE @timeDiff time

SET @timeDiff = CONVERT(time, (@EndTimestamp - cast('1900-01-01 07:30:00.000' as datetime)))

SELECT @EndTimestamp = dateadd(second, 
              datepart(hour,@timeDiff) * -3600 + 
              datepart(minute,@timeDiff) * -60 + 
              datepart(second,@timeDiff) * -1,
              @EndTimestamp)

SET @StartTimestamp = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndTimestamp)

SELECT @StartTimestamp, @EndTimestamp

SELECT '<h4>Query Range :  ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@StartTimestamp)
        + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar, @StartTimestamp, 106) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, @StartTimestamp, 108)
        + ' (UTC) to ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@EndTimestamp) + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar, @EndTimestamp, 106)
        + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, @EndTimestamp, 108) + ' (UTC)</h4>'
```